# How do I test where the nearest wall is in Minecraft 1.16?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to create a minigame in which an armor stand is spawned about ten blocks away where you're looking. The problem is, you need to be able to hit the armor stand, and if you're facing a close enough wall, it spawns in the wall. Is there any way to test where a wall is, and spawn the armor stand in front of the wall?

Comment: So, the solution to this would be to use a technic called Ray Tracing, but it is a bit complex and expensive. Where does this minigame occour? Inside a room? If that's the case, and the room is static (The room never changes size or place), we can make a slightly different solution. What is your case?